# Combine: Transform an AnyPublisher into a another AnyPublisher

Tags: swift, combine

I want to transform a Publisher to another one but I'm having an error `Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<LoginState, LoginRepositoryError>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<LoginState, Never>'`

Is my approach feasible?, I have the following code:

```
public protocol LoginUseCase {
    func login(email: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, LoginRepositoryError>
}
```

MyViewmodel.swift

```
public func login(email: String?, password: String?) -> AnyPublisher<LoginState, Never> {
    guard let email=email, !email.isEmpty else {
        return Just<LoginState>(.invalidEmail).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    guard let password=password, !password.isEmpty else {
        return Just<LoginState>(.invalidPassword).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    return loginUseCase.login(email: email, password: password)
        .map { result in
            let subject = PassthroughSubject<LoginState, Never>()
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                subject.send(.success)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                switch error {
                case .wrongPassword:
                    subject.send(.wrongPassword)
                case .userNotExist:
                    subject.send(.error)
                case .emailValidationPending:
                    subject.send(.emailValidationPending)
                }
            }
            return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63281155/560942

Comment: There are a number of issue here, but first - if `login` returns a publisher of `Bool`, how is it that your are handling the `result` like it's a `Result` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the `catch` operator to convert an `failure` completion into a `LoginState`.

I guess you have an `enum LoginRepositoryError` like this:

```
public enum LoginRepositoryError: Error {
    case wrongPassword
    case userNotExist
    case emailValidationPending
}
```

And you have an `enum LoginState` like this:

```
public enum LoginState {
    case success
    case invalidEmail
    case invalidPassword
    case wrongPassword
    case error
    case emailValidationPending
}
```

Since you want to convert your errors to `LoginState`s, let's add an initializer to do that:

```
extension LoginState {
    public init(_ repoError: LoginRepositoryError) {
        switch repoError {
        case .wrongPassword: self = .wrongPassword
        case .userNotExist: self = .error
        case .emailValidationPending: self = .emailValidationPending
        }
    }
}
```

And since the `Output` of `LoginUseCase.login` is `Bool`, let's also add an initializer to convert a `Bool` to a `LoginState`:

```
extension LoginState {
    public init(success: Bool) {
        self = success ? .success : .error
    }
}
```

Now we can use these initializers with the `map` and `catch` operators to create the `AnyPublisher<LoginState, Never>` you're looking for:

```
extension LoginUseCase {
    public func loginState(withEmail email: String?, password: String?) -> AnyPublisher<LoginState, Never> {
        guard let email=email, !email.isEmpty else {
            return Just<LoginState>(.invalidEmail).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        guard let password=password, !password.isEmpty else {
            return Just<LoginState>(.invalidPassword).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        return login(email: email, password: password)
            .map { LoginState(success: $0) }
            .catch { Just(LoginState(error: $0)) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanation.