# Combine publisher for observing data

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, combine

## Goal

Create a function that listens to changes in Firestore and publishes the result or the error

## The code

```swift
func observe<T: Codable>(document: String, inCollection collection: String) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
        let docRef = self.db.collection(collection).document(document)
        return Future<T, Error> { promise in
            let docRef = self.db.collection(collection).document(document)
            let listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                guard let object = T(dictionary: snapshot?.data()), error == nil else {
                    promise(.failure(error ?? CRUDServiceError.encodingError))
                    return
                }
                promise(.success(object))
            }
            
            // Cancel the listener when the publisher is deallocated
            let cancellable = AnyCancellable {
                listener.remove()
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

1. [Future by define produces only a single value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future), not suitable for subscribing. PassThroughSubject inside the function failed also.
2. Error leads to publisher completion. We want to keep listening to changes even after the error is received, I found multiple approaches to achieve this, but they all require specific code on subscribing. I want to handle this problem one time inside the observe function. You can read some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675235/combine-how-to-replace-catch-an-error-without-completing-the-original-publisher)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/IanKeen/934258d2d5193160391e14d25e54b084

With the above gist you can then do:

```
func observe<T: Codable>(document: String, inCollection collection: String) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    let docRef = self.db.collection(collection).document(document)
    return AnyPublisher { subscriber in
        let docRef = self.db.collection(collection).document(document)
        let listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let object = T(dictionary: snapshot?.data()), error == nil else {
                subscriber.send(completion: .failure(error ?? CRUDServiceError.encodingError))
                return
            }
            subscriber.send(object)
        }

        return AnyCancellable { listener.remove() }
    }
}
```

As for the error... A Publisher *cannot* emit any more values after it emits an error. This is a fundamental part of the contract. Then best you can do is convert the error into some other type and emit as a next event instead of a completion event.

Something like this would do it:

```
func observe<T: Codable>(document: String, inCollection collection: String) -> AnyPublisher<Result<T, Error>, Never> {
    let docRef = self.db.collection(collection).document(document)
    return AnyPublisher { subscriber in
        let docRef = self.db.collection(collection).document(document)
        let listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let object = T(dictionary: snapshot?.data()), error == nil else {
                subscriber.send(.failure(error ?? CRUDServiceError.encodingError))
                return
            }
            subscriber.send(.success(object))
        }

        return AnyCancellable { listener.remove() }
    }
}
```

But I suspect that once Firestore send an error to the callback, it too will stop calling your callback with new snapshots... So I don't think this is actually useful.