# Refresh token using Swift Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Im trying to refresh token using Combine in Swift. I put refresh part in the tryCatch part inside URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher but for some reason .sink returns as error even if this part in tryCatch is working and new token is fetched.

This is what I have in ViewModel:

```
private func testApi() {
        useCase.getSomeData
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { completion in
                switch completion {
                    case .failure(_):
                        //This is where Im getting error code!
                    case .finished: break
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                print(response
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

And this func's are in my Network class:

```
   public func request<T>(_ req: NetworkRequest) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkError> where T: Decodable, T: Encodable {
        guard let url = URL(string: req.url) else {
            return AnyPublisher(
                Fail<T, NetworkError>(error: NetworkError.badURL("Invalid Url"))
            )
        }
        
        let urlRequest = req.buildURLRequest(with: url)
        
        return URLSession
            .shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
            .tryMap { output in
                let code = (output.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 200
                
                let httpStatusCode = HTTPStatusCode(rawValue: code) ?? .noResponse
                let outputData = output.data

                let message = self.responseErrorMessage(outputData)
                guard output.response is HTTPURLResponse else {
                    throw NetworkError.serverError(code: code, error: message)
                }
                
                switch httpStatusCode {
                    case .ok, .created, .accepted:
                        
                        return output.data
                    case .badRequest, .notFound:
                        throw NetworkError.badRequest(code: code, error: message)
                    case .conflict:
                        throw NetworkError.unknown(code: code, error: message)
                    case .tokenExpired:
                        throw NetworkError.unknown(code: code, error: message)
                    case .unauthorised:
                        throw NetworkError.unauthorised(code: code, error: message)
                    case .paymentRequired, .forbidden, .methodNotAllowed, .requestTimeout, .unsupportedMediaType, .tooManyRequests:
                        throw NetworkError.unknown(code: code, error: message)
                    case .noResponse:
                        throw NetworkError.noResponse(message)
                    case .internalServerError, .serviceUnavailable:
                        throw NetworkError.serverError(code: code, error: message)
                }
            }
            .tryCatch { [weak self] error -> AnyPublisher<Data, NetworkError> in
                guard let self = self else { throw error }
                if error as? NetworkError == .unauthorised(code: 401, error: "Unauthorized") {
                    return refreshToken
                        .flatMap { _ -> AnyPublisher<Data, NetworkError> in
                            self.request(self.updateRequest(req))
                        }
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                throw error
            }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: jsonDecoder)
            .mapError { error in
                if let error = error as? NetworkError {
                    return error
                }
                return NetworkError.invalidJSON(String(describing: error))
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

This is refresh part:

```
    private var refreshToken: AnyPublisher<Void, NetworkError> {
        URLSession
            .shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: buildRefreshRequest())
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: LoginResponseData.self, decoder: jsonDecoder)
            .map { response in
                let token = response.accessToken
                UserDefaults.token = token
            }
            .mapError { error in
                if let error = error as? NetworkError {
                    return error
                }
                return NetworkError.invalidJSON(String(describing: error))
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

So in short, when I call useCase.getSomeData, I simulate token expire in debug mode by deleting token from headers, after that Im getting 401 in tryMap and in tryCatch catches that error and calling refreshToken and 'self.request(self.updateRequest(req))' is called after new token is fetched but Im not getting code in 'receiveValue: { [weak self] response ' in viewModel, instead it completes in '.sink ' as a failure.

Im fresh in Combine and trying to implement this 401/refreshToken part but I could not figure out what Im missing here.

Comment: It would be great to get some more infos. Like what error exactly are you getting? Do you only get it after the refresh happened, or also on other requests?
Also, on a side note, it's not directly relevant to your question, but it's a critical issue nonetheless:  don't ever store credentials and tokens in `UserDefaults`. Use the keychain for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine: how to replace/catch an error without completing the original publisher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675235/combine-how-to-replace-catch-an-error-without-completing-the-original-publisher)

Comment: @JanMensch I dont get errors in refresh or re-request part, only on first one and after all the process code enters in: .mapError { error in
                if let error = error as? NetworkError {
                    return error
                }
                return NetworkError.invalidJSON(String(describing: error))
            }
and in VM  Im getting this error: NetworkError.invalidJSON(String(describing: error))

For token I know this is just mvp for now,

Comment: Yes but what is the original error you are getting? Could you print it to console? From what you just said it seems to me like the response can't be parsed to `LoginResponseData`, but without the original error message we won't be able to help.

Comment: @JanMensch For some reason when I put break point on .mapError code enters three times and this is the error print descriptions:
Printing description of error:
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.String
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode String but found an array instead."
      - underlyingError : nil


Also refresh part. LoginResponseData, is success it is not failing there

Comment: You should look closely at the exact network response you're getting from the token refresh (that means: the result of `.map(\.data)`) Looking at the error it seems like the `data` you get can't be parsed into `LoginResponseData`. Some property of `LoginResponseData` is a `String`, but the JSON of that property is actually an array. That causes the decode step to fail and that error then gets sent to `mapError`. To debug this, you could print the data as string with `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` Compare the structure of the response to `LoginResponseData`.

Comment: @JanMensch If that is the case then this part in refreshToken: 
.map { response in
                let token = response.accessToken
                UserDefaults.token = token
            }

would never be executed which is not the case here, Im getting success.
Im not sure how to catch from witch Publisher mapError is called, as I said when I put breakpoint here code enter three times :S

Comment: That could be because multiple requests are attempted, right? In any case: you could check whether every time you end up in `mapError` you have the same kind of error. You might end up in there 3 times and each time for a different reason.
Speaking of multiple requests: is it maybe, that you're sending several requests and try to refresh with the same token several times? Then of course, only the first attempt will succeed and the others will result in errors and you end up in that mapError.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256709/discussion-between-clopex-and-janmensch).

Comment: When debugging Combine, to better understand your issue, use combine operators like `breakpointOnError ` or `print` directly on your stream.